# What exactly does GetExecutingAssembly(); and GetManifestResourceStream() do?

Tags: c#, .net-assembly

So one of our employs juts got a new job and quit and I'm left behind to pick up his work.
And honestly I rly don't understand what this method he has designed does.

I have read the MS documentation for the assembly methods and I'm still not any wiser.
Can some one explain what he is trying to do here?

```
        private void GetProxyServiceZipAndExtract(string extractedZipPath)
        {
            var authenticationProxyZipFullPath = Path.Combine(ClatSettings.TempDataRootDir.FullName, "AuthenticationProxy.zip");
            if(File.Exists(authenticationProxyZipFullPath))
                File.Delete(authenticationProxyZipFullPath);

            if(Directory.Exists(extractedZipPath))
                Directory.Delete(extractedZipPath, true);

            var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            var resourceDescription = "EmbeddedResources.AuthenticationProxy.zip";
            using (var embResource = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceDescription))
            {
                using (var fs = File.Create(authenticationProxyZipFullPath))
                {
                    embResource.CopyTo(fs);
                }
            }

            System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(authenticationProxyZipFullPath, extractedZipPath);

            File.Delete(authenticationProxyZipFullPath);
        }
```

Comment: There's likely an `EmbeddedResources.AuthenticationProxy.zip` file included in the project itself (or pulled in externally) that has its `Build Action` set to `embedded resource`, so it becomes part of the executable. If you open the assembly in a disassembler like ILSpy you'll see it there. `Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream` picks it up from there. This is a fairly common way to include files if putting them side by side with the assembly is not convenient enough (or subject to undesirable user tampering).

Comment: Yes there i such a file as the one u mentioned.  but what is he doing in the "Using" step

Comment: Taking the embedded resource and writing it to a new file. The method's name (`GetProxyServiceZipAndExtract`) describes the semantics fairly well. (If you're confused about what [`using`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) itself does, that's in the docs.)

Comment: Ok i get it. Thank you.